# Magento 2: Requested store is not found in product

Tags: magento-2.2.5, stores

I get this message "Requested store is not found" when I want to create a new product or edit it.

Magento 2.2.5

```
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

This already applies but does not solve

Any other solution?

[image: Requested store is not found in product]

Below error showing in log file.

> main.CRITICAL: Requested store is not found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0):
>   Requested store is not found at
>   /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:109)"}

Please help me.

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Requested store is not found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Requested store is not found at /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:109)"} []

Answer (score 1):

At line no 164 add the below code of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager:

```
if(!$storeId){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== ''){
        $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
    } else {
        $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
    }           
}
```

And then, change line no 155 of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager

=> FROM :

if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
=> To :

if (null === $this->currentStoreId || '' === $this->currentStoreId) {

Comment: Worked for me thank you. I find it ridiculous how Magento 2 can cause such issues by simply migrating it to another server

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this query in your database :

```
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';

UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';

UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
```

Comment: Not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

So, the first thing you need to do to get rid of ‘Requested Store Is Not Found’ error is to execute the following SELECT query for deleting old store data correctly.

NOTE: Make sure you’ve created a fresh backup of your database before executing the following queries!

SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE scope = ‘stores’;

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE scope_id != 1 AND scope = ‘stores’;

After that, you need to execute the following commands in your Magento 2 store database:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;

UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name=’Default’;

UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;

UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code=’NOT LOGGED IN’;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Lastly, restore the tables – store, store_group, store_website – just as they were before you migrated your Magento 2 store.

Now, try to access your Magento 2 store from a web browser & confirm that the error is resolved.